# Introduce a new variable to GLM

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, supervised-learning, actuarial-science

I have this one interview question regarding GLM model and would love some insights into method/product sense/common sense input.

-Consider this car insurance pricing model:
y (car price) = B1 * Credit Score + B2 * Age Group
Credit Score is a discrete variable
Age Group is a categorical variable (1,2,3,4) Group 1<21 yrs, Group 2: 22-30, Group 3: 30-45, Group 4: 45-60
-Now I want to add a new variable into the model which is B3 * no drunk driving history

No Drunk Driving History is categorical variable where 1 signifies yes and 0 signifies no.

My question is

1. if I never have any data regarding drunk driving history to do a GLM Fit, how do I determine/estimate the coefficient for this? I mean B3 term, statistically and in common sense. Is there any suggestion?

I was thinking Maybe research the difference in average claim cost for drunk driver and non-drunk driver using other resources and judgmentally select it?

2. if I want to do an interaction term B4 between Age Group and No Drunk Driving variable, how do I determine the coefficents B4? I was thinking of doing a correlation analysis. But I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: Re 1: if you have no data about DD history, you can't estimate the coefficient from your dataset, period.  If you're going to "judgmentally select it," then you might as well go all the way and just make up all your results, thereby saving the effort of running the GLM in the first place. ;-) Re 2: just what kind of 'correlation analysis' might you have in mind?  Indeed, how are you fitting this GLM?  Doesn't your software offer an interface for introducing interactions?  (Not all does...)

Comment: Agree on both. Both are categorical variable and no dd data given so no correlation analysis can't be done. What would you do in this case? Should I suggest aggregating all data possible on drunk driving and non drunk driving accident loss cost and use the percentage difference as coefficent?